# Looping over unquoted config values

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I'm trying to create a config map from a list of values by doing the following

```
{{- if index .Values "environmentVariables" }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "some-env.fullname" . }}
data:
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.environmentVariables }}
  {{ $key }}: {{ $value }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

With the below values

```
environmentVariables:
  SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH: /some/where/v2
  SERVER_PORT: 8080
```

But that results in the following error message

```
Error: release my-chart-env-v2-some-env-test failed: ConfigMap in version "v1" cannot be handled as a ConfigMap: v1.ConfigMap: Data: ReadString: expects " or n, parsing 106 ...ER_PORT":8... at {"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH":"/dokument-redskaber/my-chart-app/v2","SERVER_PORT":8080},"kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"my-chart-env-v2-some-env-test","app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":"Tiller","app.kubernetes.io/name":"some-env","helm.sh/chart":"some-env-0.1.0"},"name":"my-chart-env-v2","namespace":"some-env-test"}}
```

If I do

```
  {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
```

it works. But I don't (think I) want to quote all my values. And simply quoting my input value doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ConfigMap's object `data` feild requires for all values to be strings. When we have value like `8080` it reads as int.

What we can do to build `ConfigMap` object here:

**1.** Define all values as strings using `quote` function:

`values.yaml`:

```
environmentVariables:
  SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH: /some/where/v2
  SERVER_PORT: 8080
```

part of `templates/configmap.yaml`:

```
data:
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.environmentVariables }}
  {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
{{- end }}
```

**2.** Define all values as strings using double quotes:

`values.yaml`:

```
environmentVariables:
  SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH: /some/where/v2
  SERVER_PORT: 8080
```

part of `templates/configmap.yaml`:

```
data:
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.environmentVariables }}
  {{ $key }}: "{{ $value }}"
{{- end }}
```

**3.** Define all int values as string values in `values.yaml`:

`values.yaml`:

```
environmentVariables:
  SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH: /some/where/v2
  SERVER_PORT: '"8080"'
```

part of `templates/configmap.yaml`:

```
data:
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.environmentVariables }}
  {{ $key }}: {{ $value }}
{{- end }}
```

Here is some trick: when value is taken, it's basically taken as `"8080"`, which can be set exactly as a string value.